# CSS - Position a "normal" div below a div that uses "position: absolute"?

Tags: css, html

I have a background that covers the entire screen. Black line is end of viewport.

Main-div is just a container (dark blue) using position absolute.

Top-div (yellow) also using position absolute.

Middle-div (red) also using positon absolute.

Why? Well I want the Middle-div (red) to completely cover the screen vertically. Also only half should be visible - needs to scroll to see it.

Everything works fine, but how can I position the Footer-div (yellow) below the Middle-div (red)?

CSS code for Yellow Footer:

```
#footy
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;

    border: 1px solid yellow;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Right now it sits on the bottom, leaving too much gap above. Problem it must work on different resolutions. Setting bottom: 100px; will only work on this resolution....

Image:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle amigo?

Comment: Seems that setting bottom: 8%; seems to look good on several resolutions, but still a little gap of 20px...

Comment: @LloydBanks I've never done that

Comment: You can place both divs (red and yellow) in one parent :absolute div, and change childs to :normal.

Comment: @Arkham.vm Hmm... that could actually work! Wasn't thinking of that because Red has a background image in it...

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net and copy your HTML and CSS into the respective sections.  That way, you can show the whole world all of the code you have now

Comment: @LloydBanks I'm testing to place both of them inside a container div, as Arkham.vm said... Think it will solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot position elements relative to other absolutely positioned elements unless they are children of said elements, or both children of the same element when you know the position and size of both elements.

If you make the footer a child of the middle div, you can position it absolutely within:

```
#footy
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;

    border: 4px solid yellow;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I don't know all of your other CSS/HTML, but I guessed in a fiddle here, with some exaggeration of borders, etc for visual reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/NuG7T/

You can also create a wrapper around `middle` and `footy`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/NuG7T/1/

Comment: Yes I just realized that! Worked perfect with a negative value of bottom! But... overflow: hidden canceled it. So I went for your second solution with a container div. Thanks!